# WebView Crashing on AOSP 14 Emulator

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, chromium, android-source

I'm building AOSP 14, I have a working build and emulator targets running, however the included WebView is not working, and is crashing:

```
Starting VM process through Zygote failed
Failure starting process com.android.webview:sandboxed_process1:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService1:0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Starting VM process through Zygote failed
    at android.os.ZygoteProcess.start(ZygoteProcess.java:374)
    at android.os.Process.startWebView(Process.java:759)
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.startProcess(ProcessList.java:2398)
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.lambda$handleProcessStart$1(ProcessList.java:2070)
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.$r8$lambda$swBGAihsWK-ua7Y-9peg-di3_lY(ProcessList.java:0)
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.handleProcessStart(ProcessList.java:2096)
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.lambda$startProcessLocked$0(ProcessList.java:2036)
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.$r8$lambda$RYfds-QGIevfi1LguTPr20cBG60(ProcessList.java:0)
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
Caused by: android.os.ZygoteStartFailedEx: Error connecting to zygote
    at android.os.ZygoteProcess.openZygoteSocketIfNeeded(ZygoteProcess.java:1080)
    at android.os.ZygoteProcess.startViaZygote(ZygoteProcess.java:780)
    at android.os.ZygoteProcess.start(ZygoteProcess.java:365)
    at android.os.Process.startWebView(Process.java:759) 
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.startProcess(ProcessList.java:2398) 
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.lambda$handleProcessStart$1(ProcessList.java:2070) 
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.$r8$lambda$swBGAihsWK-ua7Y-9peg-di3_lY(ProcessList.java:0) 
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:0) 
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.handleProcessStart(ProcessList.java:2096) 
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.lambda$startProcessLocked$0(ProcessList.java:2036) 
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.$r8$lambda$RYfds-QGIevfi1LguTPr20cBG60(ProcessList.java:0) 
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:0) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 
    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46) 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection refused
    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connectLocal(Native Method)
    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.connect(LocalSocketImpl.java:259)
    at android.net.LocalSocket.connect(LocalSocket.java:162)
    at android.os.ZygoteProcess$ZygoteState.connect(ZygoteProcess.java:194)
    at android.os.ZygoteProcess.attemptConnectionToPrimaryZygote(ZygoteProcess.java:1034)
    at android.os.ZygoteProcess.openZygoteSocketIfNeeded(ZygoteProcess.java:1065)
    at android.os.ZygoteProcess.startViaZygote(ZygoteProcess.java:780) 
    at android.os.ZygoteProcess.start(ZygoteProcess.java:365) 
    at android.os.Process.startWebView(Process.java:759) 
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.startProcess(ProcessList.java:2398) 
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.lambda$handleProcessStart$1(ProcessList.java:2070) 
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.$r8$lambda$swBGAihsWK-ua7Y-9peg-di3_lY(ProcessList.java:0) 
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:0) 
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.handleProcessStart(ProcessList.java:2096) 
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.lambda$startProcessLocked$0(ProcessList.java:2036) 
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.$r8$lambda$RYfds-QGIevfi1LguTPr20cBG60(ProcessList.java:0) 
    at com.android.server.am.ProcessList$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:0) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 
    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

I have tried extracting `com.android.webview` from a working stock emulator and installing that though the result is the same.

Any ideas? I have made no modifications to the system image.

Some additional logs from boot:

```
webview_zygote                       A  runtime.cc:3369] Check failed: !IsZygote() 
webview_zygote                       E  holding "abort lock" at point where thread suspension is expected
webview_zygote                       A  runtime.cc:691] Runtime aborting...
                                        runtime.cc:691] Dumping all threads without mutator lock held
                                        runtime.cc:691] All threads:
                                        runtime.cc:691] DALVIK THREADS (5):
                                        runtime.cc:691] "ReferenceQueueDaemon" prio=5 tid=2 Waiting
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | group="" sCount=1 ucsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x15cc47a0 self=0x71af0be330
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | sysTid=817 nice=4 cgrp=foreground sched=0/0 handle=0x7150c01cb0
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | state=S schedstat=( 300459 310541 4 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | stack=0x7150afe000-0x7150b00000 stackSize=1039KB
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | held mutexes=
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #00 pc 00062e1c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+28) (BuildId: a87908b48b368e6282bcc9f34bcfc28c)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #01 pc 002325d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks+212) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #02 pc 006d4020  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Monitor::Wait+488) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #03 pc 006d709c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Monitor::Wait+676) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #04 pc 006f33c0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::mirror::Object::Wait+140) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #05 pc 006f2ecc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Object_waitJI+168) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native method)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   - waiting on <0x0d43eb21> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:386)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:524)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:239)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   - locked <0x0d43eb21> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:145)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                        runtime.cc:691] 
                                        runtime.cc:691] "FinalizerDaemon" prio=5 tid=4 Waiting
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | group="" sCount=1 ucsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x15cc4830 self=0x71af097f50
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | sysTid=818 nice=4 cgrp=foreground sched=0/0 handle=0x714eaf7cb0
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | state=S schedstat=( 60041 4885958 3 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | stack=0x714e9f4000-0x714e9f6000 stackSize=1039KB
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | held mutexes=
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #00 pc 00062e1c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+28) (BuildId: a87908b48b368e6282bcc9f34bcfc28c)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #01 pc 002325d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks+212) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #02 pc 006d4020  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Monitor::Wait+488) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #03 pc 006d709c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Monitor::Wait+676) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #04 pc 006f33c0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::mirror::Object::Wait+140) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #05 pc 006f2ecc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Object_waitJI+168) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native method)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   - waiting on <0x04155b46> (a java.lang.Object)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:386)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:210)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   - locked <0x04155b46> (a java.lang.Object)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:231)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:309)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:145)
webview_zygote                       A  runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                        runtime.cc:691] 
                                        runtime.cc:691] "FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" prio=5 tid=5 Waiting
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | group="" sCount=1 ucsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x15cc48c0 self=0x71af09d2c0
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | sysTid=819 nice=4 cgrp=foreground sched=0/0 handle=0x714e9edcb0
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | state=S schedstat=( 105250 5490000 4 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | stack=0x714e8ea000-0x714e8ec000 stackSize=1039KB
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | held mutexes=
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #00 pc 00062e1c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+28) (BuildId: a87908b48b368e6282bcc9f34bcfc28c)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #01 pc 002325d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks+212) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #02 pc 006d4020  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Monitor::Wait+488) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #03 pc 006d709c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Monitor::Wait+676) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #04 pc 006f33c0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::mirror::Object::Wait+140) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #05 pc 006f2ecc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Object_waitJI+168) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native method)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   - waiting on <0x0d0b6107> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:386)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:524)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepUntilNeeded(Daemons.java:428)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   - locked <0x0d0b6107> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:408)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:145)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                        runtime.cc:691] 
                                        runtime.cc:691] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | group="" sCount=1 ucsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x71f67cd8 self=0xb4000071af091010
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | sysTid=810 nice=0 cgrp=foreground sched=0/0 handle=0x743272b4f8
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | state=S schedstat=( 35525253 2600625 37 ) utm=1 stm=1 core=0 HZ=100
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | stack=0x7fd0830000-0x7fd0832000 stackSize=8188KB
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | held mutexes=
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #00 pc 000b8758  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__ppoll+8) (BuildId: a87908b48b368e6282bcc9f34bcfc28c)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #01 pc 00072ed0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (poll+92) (BuildId: a87908b48b368e6282bcc9f34bcfc28c)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #02 pc 00039c0c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libjavacore.so (Linux_poll+584) (BuildId: bf1f2308a74762c892198faacfa20a44)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at libcore.io.Linux.poll(Native method)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.poll(ForwardingOs.java:573)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.poll(BlockGuardOs.java:283)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at android.system.Os.poll(Os.java:531)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteServer.runSelectLoop(ZygoteServer.java:486)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at com.android.internal.os.ChildZygoteInit.runZygoteServer(ChildZygoteInit.java:125)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at com.android.internal.os.WebViewZygoteInit.main(WebViewZygoteInit.java:147)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
                                        runtime.cc:691] 
                                        runtime.cc:691] "HeapTaskDaemon" prio=5 tid=3 Runnable
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | group="" sCount=0 ucsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x15cc4710 self=0x71af09b6f0
webview_zygote                       A  runtime.cc:691]   | sysTid=816 nice=4 cgrp=foreground sched=0/0 handle=0x71511fbcb0
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | state=R schedstat=( 260418 704208 7 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | stack=0x71510f8000-0x71510fa000 stackSize=1039KB
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #00 pc 006db6c0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::DumpNativeStack+180) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #01 pc 0082ad3c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Thread::DumpStack const+364) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #02 pc 0084bbb0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run+452) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #03 pc 00845574  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint+904) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #04 pc 00844ce0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::ThreadList::Dump+308) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #05 pc 007dc994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::AbortState::Dump const+196) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #06 pc 007c806c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Runtime::Abort+448) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #07 pc 000417d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter::$_0::__invoke+80) (BuildId: 86bef7ce19ab410597d5aa825f150404)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #08 pc 00040d58  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage+352) (BuildId: 86bef7ce19ab410597d5aa825f150404)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #09 pc 007dae6c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Runtime::NotifyStartupCompleted+220) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #10 pc 00816f94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::StartupCompletedTask::Run+56) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #11 pc 004d9048  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::RunAllTasks+68) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(Native method)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:687)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:145)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                        runtime.cc:691] 
                                        runtime.cc:691] Aborting thread:
                                        runtime.cc:691] "HeapTaskDaemon" prio=5 tid=3 Native
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | group="" sCount=0 ucsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x15cc4710 self=0x71af09b6f0
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | sysTid=816 nice=4 cgrp=foreground sched=0/0 handle=0x71511fbcb0
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | state=R schedstat=( 10115793 22501582 59 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | stack=0x71510f8000-0x71510fa000 stackSize=1039KB
                                        runtime.cc:691]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #00 pc 006db6c0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::DumpNativeStack+180) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #01 pc 0082ad3c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Thread::DumpStack const+364) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #02 pc 00826b38  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Thread::Dump const+196) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #03 pc 007dcc78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::AbortState::DumpThread const+96) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #04 pc 007dca78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::AbortState::Dump const+424) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #05 pc 007c806c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Runtime::Abort+448) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)

webview_zygote                       A  runtime.cc:691]   native: #06 pc 000417d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter::$_0::__invoke+80) (BuildId: 86bef7ce19ab410597d5aa825f150404)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #07 pc 00040d58  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage+352) (BuildId: 86bef7ce19ab410597d5aa825f150404)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #08 pc 007dae6c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Runtime::NotifyStartupCompleted+220) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #09 pc 00816f94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::StartupCompletedTask::Run+56) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #10 pc 004d9048  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::RunAllTasks+68) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #11 pc 00010d14  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (art_jni_trampoline+116) (BuildId: b3f7a8fb043a32cde20ffbee691af59373143f85)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #12 pc 00046be8  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal+200) (BuildId: b3f7a8fb043a32cde20ffbee691af59373143f85)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #13 pc 0001eb0c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run+172) (BuildId: b3f7a8fb043a32cde20ffbee691af59373143f85)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #14 pc 00160778  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+72) (BuildId: 728c0953f3a7edba65ca48d4e8127da039f33da3)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #15 pc 0091efa4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+612) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #16 pc 002183e0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke+384) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #17 pc 00840ed8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::detail::ShortyTraits<86>::Type art::ArtMethod::InvokeInstance<86>+212) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #18 pc 008254d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::detail::ShortyTraits<86>::Type art::ArtMethod::InvokeVirtual<86>+268) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #19 pc 00824248  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libartd.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback+980) (BuildId: f75d06583763748336ec983d04e9b0a0)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #20 pc 000cb6a8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start+208) (BuildId: a87908b48b368e6282bcc9f34bcfc28c)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   native: #21 pc 0006821c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: a87908b48b368e6282bcc9f34bcfc28c)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(Native method)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:687)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:145)
                                        runtime.cc:691]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                        runtime.cc:691] 
webview_zygote                       A  Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 816 (HeapTaskDaemon), pid 810 (webview_zygote)
pid-1507                             A  Cmdline: webview_zygote
pid-1507                             A  pid: 810, tid: 816, name: HeapTaskDaemon  >>> webview_zygote <<<
```